# Script to refresh SDProp immediately?

Tags: active-directory

I'm reading [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn535499(v=ws.11)), how can I refresh sdprop immediately on a Windows 2016 domain controller?

I'm trying to do this in command line, but [referenced link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/fc74972f-b267-4c1a-8716-0f5b48cf52b9?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the document above is quite vague, I couldn't get it.

Does anyone know?

Comment: https://github.com/edemilliere/ADSI/blob/master/Invoke-ADSDPropagation.ps1

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks! I confirm Invoke-ADSDPropagation works for me, you may add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be made somewhat generic due to there are other commands that may be run. For example, removeLingeringObject is commonly used.

Source: https://github.com/edemilliere/ADSI/blob/master/Invoke-ADSDPropagation.ps1

```
Function Invoke-ADSDPropagation{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Invoke a SDProp task on the PDCe.
.DESCRIPTION
    Make an LDAP call to trigger SDProp.
.EXAMPLE
    Invoke-ADSDPropagation
    By default, RunProtectAdminGroupsTask is used.
.EXAMPLE
    Invoke-ADSDPropagation -TaskName FixUpInheritance
    Use the legacy FixUpInheritance task name for Windows Server 2003 and earlier.
.PARAMETER TaskName
    Name of the task to use.
        - FixUpInheritance for legacy OS
        - RunProtectAdminGroupsTask for recent OS
.INPUTS
.OUTPUTS
.NOTES
    You can track progress with:
    Get-Counter -Counter '\directoryservices(ntds)\ds security descriptor propagator runtime queue' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue
.LINK
    http://ItForDummies.net
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage='Name of the domain where to force SDProp to run',
        Position=0)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 2 -Quiet})]
    [String]$DomainName = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name,

    [ValidateSet('RunProtectAdminGroupsTask','FixUpInheritance')]
    [String]$TaskName = 'RunProtectAdminGroupsTask'
)

try{
$DomainContext = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext('domain',$DomainName)
    $DomainObject = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($DomainContext)
    
    Write-Verbose -Message "Detected PDCe is $($DomainObject.PdcRoleOwner.Name)."
    $RootDSE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$($DomainObject.PdcRoleOwner.Name)/RootDSE") 
    $RootDSE.UsePropertyCache = $false 
    $RootDSE.Put($TaskName, "1") # RunProtectAdminGroupsTask & fixupinheritance
    $RootDSE.SetInfo()
}
catch{
    throw "Can't invoke SDProp on $($DomainObject.PdcRoleOwner.Name) !"
}
```

}